# Sqlite3 database size limit is 10MB?

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm testing a Drupal website running unmodified Sqlite3 on Ubuntu server 32-bit.

But when the database size reach 9.233kB, the next data write is failed.

According to SQlite FAQ, the limit is much bigger than this.

I dont know what happened and what to do to solve this.

Comment: Maybe your disk is full?

Comment: no, plenty of space available

Comment: does running `ulimit -f` from the shell produce output besides "unlimited"?

Comment: Yes, `ulimit -f` produce `unlimited`

Comment: do you have an exception/error log?

Comment: no I dont have any error log. I think this is not sqlite problem